# view at same position in absolute layout in android

Tags: android

I have one absolute layout which contains many ImageViews. I have implemented Drog and Drop functions for all imageview. Now what happen when suppose i drag one imageview over another imageview then first view goes back side because it have been added first compaire to another one . I need that moving   view always visible on top.

So can i solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you probably need to remove your view and add it again so it is on top when you start moving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to avoid this is to call .bringToFront() on your ImageView when you begin your dragging code.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront%28%29